# How to give flatpak apps access to system libraries (eg. give Intellij access to system JDK)?

Tags: flatpak, permissions

So I am new to elementary OS and also flatpaks in general. How do you give access to flatpak apps so that they have access to system libraries? I can't access the system JDK with Intellij for example, or Pycharm, or like any other IDE? I have tried the flatpak override command with "sudo flatpak override com.jetbrains.IntelliJ-IDEA-Ultimate --filesystem=/usr/lib/jvm" but this didn't work. This is just one example and I want to do this kind of thing to different apps as well.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!